# In Typeorm, how do you find filter for records with array relation length > 0

Tags: typeorm

I have an entity like this

```js
@Entity()
export class Order {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @OneToMany(() => Transaction, (t) => t.order, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  transactions: Transaction[];
}
```

How do I use `find()` to search for all records with `transactions.length > 0`?

I prefer to use `find()` but if it is not possible should I use the query builder?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do this:

```
import { IsNull, Not } from "typeorm";

await getRepository(Order).findOne({
  relations: ['transactions'],
  where: { 
    transactions: Not(IsNull())
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work since `NULL` differs `[]`

Comment: @MaximeLafarie It used to work but they changed it recently. I'm not aware of any replacement, unfortunately. Have switched to the query builder so I was able to update typeorm.